# How do I open a Discord direct chat to user and spesific channel from my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a flutter app. I have already provided a direct WA link in the app using the url_launcher plugin.

Now I plan to open a Discord with my discord server and direct message to other user in the user's phone. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an unoffical Discord protocol documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/ghostrider-05/8f1a0bfc27c7c4509b4ea4e8ce718af0).

To open a direct chat you have to know the direct chat room's id.

For example:

```
discord://-/channels/@me/<room id>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).